# Log Storage/Indexing Tools

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, bigdata

Whats the best tools for storage/indexing of system logs, with a good search API. I wanna implement on my whole system something like

```
logs.put({
   type: 'SOME_USER_ACTION', 
   result: 'SUCCESS', detail:'The user make some action on system', 
   user: 'ID:Name|user@email.com'
});
```

And on admin section I need get back this data:

```
logs.search({
   type: 'SOME_USER_ACTION', 
   user: 'ID'
});
```

I'm don't looking for some library, but for tools. I'm already seen about [Graylog](https://www.graylog.org/) and [Elastic Stack](https://www.elastic.co/products), and I'm not sure if these are the best options. Maybe Amazon has something better, but I don't know.

PS: If more than one tool is needed, a flow example will be helpful

Comment: AWS offers hosted Elasticsearch btw: https://aws.amazon.com/de/elasticsearch-service/

Answer (score 1):

- You may want to look at [AWS CloudWatch Logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html). It provides you APIs to manage your log groups, post log events, search logs using filters and paging.
- I usually setup a AWS CloudWatch logs agent on each instance or
  docker container, and publish all logs to AWS CloudWatch using the
  daemon. All lambda function logs are also created as CloudWatch logs. Visit 
  [Cloud Watch Logs Agent](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AgentReference.html) for more details.
- If you are already using AWS, CloudWatch is the recommended way to go and is
  available for use out of the box.
- You can even configure your log retention policies to 1 day to x Months
  and later archive to Amazon Glacier for future retrieval. You are
  charged with the amount of GBs ingested per month + total amount of
  data stored per month.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I don't found how to send my logs for CloudWatch, on Javascript SDK just have management of alarms, dashboard and etc...

Comment: you need to see CloudWatchLogs and not CloudWatch. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatchLogs.html.

Comment: OMG, I'm so dumb... hahah... Thank you. I've just one more question CloudWatchLogs support custom fields, like `type` and `user`?

Comment: You can put any json data in the logs and later filter on it. You can add custom metrics to build a dashboard.